# How and where can I report a bug in a RADStudio GetIt package, specifically for the googletest package?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio, bug-reporting

I have found several errors in googlemock related C++Builder project files distributed with the [googletest GetIt package](https://getitnow.embarcadero.com/google-test/). These errors are part of the additional C++Builder-specific project files, and are not contained in the googletest GitHub project as published by Google, therefore I cannot report them to the [GitHub issues of googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues).

How and where can I report the project file bugs that I have found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, only Embarcadero can make changes to GetIt's content.

Embarcadero's current bug tracker is known as "Quality Portal" (https://quality.embarcadero.com).